# Sonar Qube - Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer

Tags: sonarqube

I saw the message "Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer." when I run the sonar runner. How can I make the bytecode available to the analyser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sonar-runner to analyse your project?  If so, you'll need to point the config to where your byte code lives (including jars).  See the documentation here:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode

An alternative is to analyse your project with Maven.